# How to open files in the current tab in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

Is there a way to open a file in the current tab that is open, rather than opening it in a new tab every time? I'm essentially looking for navigation behavior more similar to Xcode, where the files opened are kept on a navigation stack so I can move backward/forward between files that were open in the same tab. The default in Android studio appears to be that every new file is opened in a new tab.

I only ask because I'm the type that prefers to explicitly manage what tabs are open, and not have to close tabs after a quick glance at a file.

Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

Under `File > Settings > Editor > General > Editor Tabs` set `Tab Limit` to 1

Comment: While this effectively opens new files in the same tab, it's not the exact behavior I was hoping for. This makes it so it's never possible to have multiple tabs. I'm hoping that this isn't the only way.

Comment: Apart from coupling this with a split view (Right click on tab and click split) there really isn't any other way I'm aware of doing this.

Answer (score 3):

Even though it's an old question I believe more accurate answer is:

```
File > Settings > Editor > General > Editor Tabs
```

Select checkbox at the bottom

```
Open declaration source in the same tab
```

This way the source file will replace the current tab while navigating through declarations. Besides you still get to keep other tabs open. **No need to limit number of tabs.**

Comment: This should be marked as correct answer. Thank @Fatih

Answer (score 2):

Applying @ChrisStillwell's comment, for Mac users I believe that you want

`Android Studio > Preferences > Editor > General > Editor Tabs` then change the tab limit to 1.